# MVC3 Get Ajax Posted Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

in postback requests when i need posted values i do like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //i need to get values in here not in action method argument
    //i know this works but not like this --> ActionResult Index(string Name)

    string Name = Request.Form["Name"];
}
```

but in ajax requests this does not work,,and i cant find where mvc store ajax posted values

Any Suggestions?

Comment: it posts as method parameters `public ActionResult Index(string name)`

Comment: If you're using AJAX *Get* then you have to use `Request.QueryString["Name"]`

Comment: @DarthVader i need to get values in the method not in argument,,i know this works but not like this --> ActionResult Index(string Name)

Comment: @raoofhojat you need to post your code and the exact error you're seeing.  The problem could be any number of things (AJAX post, URL route maps, encoding ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little late to the party, but I will offer an alternative that will allow you to access Request.Form with an Ajax post/form.  This was tested in MVC 4 and jQuery 1.9.1.

If the controller's Request.Form is not populating for your Ajax post, it is likely because you are manually serializing and sending the data to the controller with a contentType of `application/json` (a common scenario).

Here is an jQuery.ajax example that will **NOT** populate Request.Form on the controller.

```
    // JSON serialized form data.
    var data = {"id" : "1234", "name" : "Dave"};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceUrl,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data || {}),
        success: function () { }
    });
```

Changing the contentType will cause the controller to process the post like a form submission.

```
    // Form encoded data.  See jQuery.serialize().
    var data = "id=1234&name=Dave";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceUrl,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function () { }
    });
```

You can also leave contentType undefined as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` it is the jQuery default.

I would note that I only used [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to better illustrate what is going on.  You could also use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), though you will still need to send form encoded data

Answer (score 0):

The ajax posted values won't appear in the request from collection however you can use the `ValueProvider` infrastructure in MVC to get the your Ajax posted value:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Name = ValueProvider.GetValue("Name").AttemptedValue;
}
```

Or the `Request.InputStream` contains all the posted data what you can read and deserailize as you want:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        var data = (Dictionary<string,object>)serializer
                      .DeserializeObject(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        //assuming your posted data looks like this: '{"Name": "test"}'
        string name = data["Name"].ToString();
    }
}
```

But I highly recommend that you should not fight against the MVC infrastructure and recive the data as your action paratemer:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{

}
```